# Android ListView - Use Whole Row

Tags: android, listview

I have a **custom listview** with the following layout (list_single.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt"
            android:textSize="24dp" android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingTop="20dp" android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="64dp" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Then i have a CustomList **extender class** that is assigning this layout:

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] web;
    private final Integer[] imageId;
    public CustomList(Activity context,
                String[] web, Integer[] imageId) {
            super(context, R.layout.list_single, web);
            this.context = context;
            this.web = web;
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null, true);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        txtTitle.setText(web[position]);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Then inside the OnCreate event handler i add a listener:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
```

However the only clickable area in the row is the icon though i want the whole row to be clickable. I checked some other similar questions here but i couldn't find solution for the TableLayout.

Thank you so much

Comment: For it you should use `ListView` not `TableLayout`.

Comment: is it necessary to use tableLayout ?

Comment: Not sure if i should TableLayout because i just followed tutorial which obviously was using  such layout.

Comment: Just remove the table layout and use Relative or Linear layout.These layout will improve the listview performance as well.Please let us know if you are getting same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following yours suggestions i replaced Table with Relative layout and now everything works as expected. Thank you so much guys. It's much appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp" android:paddingLeft="20dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:textSize="24dp" 
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingTop="20dp" 
        android:paddingLeft="84dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Sorry for not being able to vote (it requires minimum 15 points which i do not have as i am n00b) THANK You so much for the help. It's much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you should set

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

in your table layout. Generally its not a good idea to use table layout n row layout of listview. For your case, you could easily do that by any other layout e.g. linearlayout,relativelayout etc

Comment: This didn't help. Evenmore the listview became not-responsive. Btw could you guys show me an example of using a relative layout to customize the list view. I just need an image to the positioned to the left of the text and to have the whole row clickable. That's all i need. Nothing fancy :)